# While decrypting the web.config get an error

Tags: asp.net, configuration, command-line, encryption

I am just trying to test this.

And here is my command line:

aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connectionStrings" c:\web.config

And this is the error I got.
Error – "The configuration for physical path ‘C:\Web.Config’ cannot be opened.

And the permissions of that file is not read only.

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: I got the solution.I don't know why after putting web.config into a  folder , it worked.

Comment: and also I tried c:\xyz after taking off web.config

Comment: and what was the answer, so everyone else can benefit?

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old post but I was searching for it myself today and found that if you omit the file name it will pickup Web.config in the directory you specify:

> `aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" c:\temp`

If you add a trailing `\` or the full name `c:\temp\Web.config` it will still fail.

Also, the `c:\` may have been an administrator privilege issue reading and writing to the root.

Cheers

Comment: Worked for me.  Not sure why it didn't work when including the file name though.

Answer (score -2):

You should keep web.config in a folder close the application code. The root folder (c:) is an admin-only folder and shouldn't be used for anything!